# Algorithm to build nested menu (tree) from record set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an array where each item has fields (Name, ItemID, ParentID, Level).

Level is how deep into the tree the node is placed. Root level items have Level = 0 and ParentID = NULL.

How do I keep track of the parents and build this tree?

Current (incomplete) Algorithm looks like:

For items in record set:

- If current item level = 0, it is a root node.
- Else if current item level is greater than previous item level, AddNode a child to previous item.
- Else if current item level is equal to previous item level, AddNode as a sibling to previous item.
- Else if current item level is lower than previous item level, I need to go back up a level and insert a node (how?).

The array is sorted in a way that we can be sure whether the next item is an immediate child or sibling based on the 'Level'. The items in record set are represented as iterable objects in an array of arrays.

Thank you for your help to determine the correct algorithm and approach to solve this.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** ideas / finings / code.

Comment: do you speak any python or are you looking for an answer in pseudo language ? An example is often a good starting point, before diving into the algorithm itself...

Comment: Btw, isn't there any redundancy into your data :  I mean, the level, at least can certainly be calculated from the other datas. 1 question : does any node have at most one parent ?

Comment: Solved and answered. @Smed yes each node has at most one parent.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I thought I did that. I was stuck on the most basic level. Anyway, I updated with my answer after 6 hours of work.

Comment: The best answers are the ones you find for yourself ! Good job Niko

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Keep track of parents in an array, and remove them as needed when you know they won't be a parent ever again. The record set is ordered on the database level to ensure that every child of a particular parent is directly consecutive in the list. This affords me some ease of programming logic.

This seems like an unusual circumstance, alas, my code below creates the desired result.

[image]